# Why won't this Javascript method keep calling itself?

Tags: javascript, methods, settimeout

I have a JavaScript object with a privileged method. When this method has completed, I would like it to call itself (after a small timeout) and continue running indefinitely.  Unfortunately, the method only runs twice, then it stops without any error (tested in Chrome and IE with the same results).

The code is as follows:

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    this.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        setTimeout(this.testMethod, 2000);
    };
}

var myTest = new Test();
myTest.testMethod();
```

I would expect to get the alert every two seconds, but instead it only shows the alert twice, then stops.  You can see a [live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/Z7rEB/).  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: I believe the setTimeout function takes the function name as string that's why.

Comment: No, setTimeout can also accept a function reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you first call it with "myTest.testMethod();" the "this" keyword is bond to your "myTest" object, when the timeout fires the "window" object is bond to "this" keyword and "this.testMethod" is equivalent to "window.testMethod".
Try:

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    this.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        setTimeout((function(self){
            return function(){self.testMethod();};
        })(this), 2000);
    };
}

var myTest = new Test();
myTest.testMethod();
```

Or:

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    this.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){self.testMethod();}, 2000);
    };
}

var myTest = new Test();
myTest.testMethod();
```

Comment: +1 For the better explanation, and showing the double-nesting closure approach.

Comment: I'm going against the popular vote, and picking this as the answer. :)  I was mostly interested in *why* this works the way it does (especially why setTimeout worked the first time through, but not the second).  Most of the other answers focus on workarounds. While those are helpful, it's not really what I was looking for.  Your answer most clearly explained what's actually happening... thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I have no idea why my answer is so popular.

Answer (score 10):

Because `this` outside the function is not the same as `this` inside the function. Try instead:

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    var me = this;
    this.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        setTimeout(me.testMethod, 2000);
    };
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `arguments.callee` for the callback and avoid the closure entirely.

Comment: You should use **var** me = ...., without var you will never know what else are you changing.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `var`, I've edited the answer. (@pst, rather than downvoting, you have enough rep you could have edited it yourself.)

Comment: The downvote is to encourage self-change :) The answer is correct otherwise, and easy to change to an upvote later.

Comment: @pst Thank you so much for encouraging me to change it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    this.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() { self.testMethod(); }, 2000);
    };
}
```

or use **setInterval**.

Comment: +1 This is a clever method of moving the closure in closer. It also mentions using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3):

because the `this` in your setTimeout is referring to the local function `testMethod` not `Test` -- essentially, you are saying `setTimeout( testMethod.testMethod, 2000 )`

```
function Test() {
    // ... private variables that testMethod needs to access ...
    var self = this;
    self.testMethod = function() {
        alert("Hello, from the method.");
        setTimeout(self.testMethod, 2000);
    };
}

var myTest = new Test();
myTest.testMethod();
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `arguments.callee` for the callback and avoid the closure entirely.

Comment: +1 Unlike the currently top-voted answer this correctly creates a closure around a *lexical* variable, `self`.